# Link serial /dev/ttyUSB0 to /dev/ttyS0

Tags: ubuntu, serial, arduino

I have a program that communicates with an Arduino through the serial port but somehow the Arduino is showing up in the computer as /dev/ttyUSB0 and not /dev/ttyS0, which is what the program is attempting to connect to. This program used to work some months ago without any problem. Any ideas? I'm running Ubuntu 18.04